# Present tabular data with CSS, where too-wide cells don't ruin things

Tags: html, css, tabular

I have rows of data that I want to present in fixed-size columns.  For example:

```
Name     City       Number
Adam     Anaheim    714 555 5555
Bob      Barstow    760 555 5555
...      ...        ...
```

However, occasionally one of the column's data is too big to fit. If that happens, I want it to affect as few neighboring cells as possible, not the whole row if it doesn't have to.

Here's what I **DO** want:

```
Name     City       Number
Adam     Anaheim    714 555 5555
Bob      Barstow    760 555 5555
Constantine  Canyon 805 555 5555  # Notice how phone number is still aligned :)
```

Here's what I **DON'T** want:

```
Name     City       Number
Adam     Anaheim    714 555 5555
Bob      Barstow    760 555 5555
Constantine  Canyon     805 555 5555  # Notice how phone number is also shifted :(
```

How do I do this with HTML/CSS (no javascript please)?

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/evoka3) with a non-working solution, where you can play around and see for yourself.

**UPDATE** Here's a summary of the accepted answer, when you have N columns:

The first N-1 columns have to be wrapped inside a DIV style="display: inline-block" whose min-width is the combined width of the first N-1 columns. Then inside that DIV, the first N-2 columns have to be wrapped inside a similar div whose min-width is the combined width of the first N-2 columns. Continue this all the way down...

It's not pretty, but it works, and is manageable for small N.

Comment: Can you post your current HTML markup?

Comment: I tried using left-floated DIVs with a min-width, but that didn't work. I briefly tried a vanilla TABLE, but that causes all the columns to grow to fit the largest data.

Comment: If you want to align data, won't columns by definition have to grow to fit the largest data?

Comment: I want to align the data *as much as possible*, but I have a fixed total width that I'd like to stay inside for the majority of cases. If I have 100 rows, and 99 of them fit, it's better to show those 99 nicely, than to have the whole table full of whitespace just to accommodate 1 row's data.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in plain HTML/CSS without using Javascript. To my knowledge, you'll always end up either with `Constantine` overlapping `Canyon` or with a gap after `Canyon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I couldn't find a way to do it with a normal table (partly because of the wrapper elements required, partly because IE wouldn't behave properly) so the solution below uses divs.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test Case</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-size:11px; font-family: "Courier New"; }
    * { margin:0; padding:0; }

    .col, .span { display:inline-block; }
    .col1 { min-width:12ex; }
    .span2 { min-width:30ex; }
    .span3 { min-width:40ex; }

    /* IE6 */
    * html .col { display:inline; padding-right:1ex; }
    * html .span { display:inline; white-space:nowrap; }
    * html .col1 { width:12ex; }
    * html .span2 { width:30ex; }
    * html .span3 { width:40ex; }

    /* IE7 */
    *:first-child+html .col { display:inline; padding-right:1ex; }
    *:first-child+html .span { display:inline; }
</style>
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2 span">
      <div class="col1 col">Name</div>
      <div class="col">City</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">Number</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2 span">
      <div class="col1 col">Adam</div>
      <div class="col">Anaheim</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">714 555 5555</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2 span">
      <div class="col1 col">Bob</div>
      <div class="col">Barstow</div>
    </div>      
    <div class="col">760 555 5555</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3 span">
      <div class="span2 span">
        <div class="col1 col">Constantine</div>
        <div class="col">Canyon</div>
      </div>         
      <div class="col">805 555 5555</div>
    </div>         
    <div class="col"># Notice how phone number is still aligned :)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should be clear how to expand this idea to further columns by using wrappers "span4", "span5", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a div inside the td <`td><div class="mydiv">your content</div></td>`

Then you give in css `.mydiv {overflow:auto;}` and this will add scrolls when is needed without ruin your table.

Edit - I just saw that you use divs instead of table. Why This?

In any case you can use the properties `display:table;` `display:table-row;` and `display:table-cell;` to represent tabular data.

Here an example http://jsbin.com/evoka3/3

Comment: I'd like to avoid scroll-bars if possible. And in the example I showed, it's (theoretically) possible to present the data without them.

Comment: I don't think that is possible without javascript and even without scrollbars. Maybe there is another alternative that someone knows. Can you give as a live example at jsbin.com to "play" with it?

Comment: Good idea - I added jsbin link to the end of the question.